# How do I delete all channels in a guild discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to add a command in my discord bot called `!boom` that deletes all channels in the guild it was sent in. How can I do that?

Comment: You are responsible for researching and trying to make that on your own, This forum is for us to help you troubleshoot errors. Try making one yourself first then come back if you have any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete every channel, you can use this:

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.each((channel) => {
  channel.delete()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
};
```